# LINQ remove items with specific value in group by

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have code where I am grouping my requirements by Opportunity Number as below :

```
        List<Requirement> result = requirements
                                    .GroupBy(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
                                    .Select(cl => new Requirement
                                    {
                                        CRMOpportunityNumber = cl.First().CRMOpportunityNumber,
                                        OpportunityTitle = cl.First().OpportunityTitle,
                                        ClientName = cl.First().ClientName,
                                        TentativeStartDate = cl.Min(c => c.TentativeStartDate),
                                        TotalPositions = cl.Sum(c => c.Required),
                                        RegionName = cl.First().RegionName,
                                        TotalCVProposed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count),
                                        TotalDeployed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true)),
                                        NetGap = cl.Sum(c => c.Required) - cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true)),
                                    }).OrderByDescending(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber).ToList();
```

Now I don't want to include those requirements in grouping (result) which have all CATEGORY field values equal to "work commenced" .

Requirement class has a field category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exclude the 'Work Commenced' category using a Where clause before grouping

```
    List<Requirement> result = requirements
                                .Where(r => r.Category != "work commenced")
                                .GroupBy(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
                                .Select(cl => new Requirement
                                {
                                    CRMOpportunityNumber = cl.First().CRMOpportunityNumber,
                                    OpportunityTitle = cl.First().OpportunityTitle,
                                    ClientName = cl.First().ClientName,
                                    TentativeStartDate = cl.Min(c => c.TentativeStartDate),
                                    TotalPositions = cl.Sum(c => c.Required),
                                    RegionName = cl.First().RegionName,
                                    TotalCVProposed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count),
                                    TotalDeployed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true)),
                                    NetGap = cl.Sum(c => c.Required) - cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true)),
                                }).OrderByDescending(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber).ToList();
```

**Edit**

If you want to exclude groups where all requirements have a category of 'work commenced', how about:

```
List<Requirement> result = requirements
    .GroupBy(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
    .Where(cl => cl.All(l => l.Category != "work commenced"))
    .Select(cl => new Requirement
    {
        CRMOpportunityNumber = cl.First().CRMOpportunityNumber,
        OpportunityTitle = cl.First().OpportunityTitle,
        ClientName = cl.First().ClientName,
        TentativeStartDate = cl.Min(c => c.TentativeStartDate),
        TotalPositions = cl.Sum(c => c.Required),
        RegionName = cl.First().RegionName,
        TotalCVProposed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count),
        TotalDeployed = cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true)),
        NetGap = cl.Sum(c => c.Required) - cl.Sum(c => c.Associates.Count(x => x.IsIdentified == true))
    }).OrderByDescending(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i think this will exclude any requirement with "work commenced". I want to exclude those grouped requirement which has its categoriy of ALL grouped requirements equal to "work commenced".            category of ALL  requirements within a group should not be "work commenced"

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exclude groups only if EVERY requirement in the group has a category of 'Work Commenced'?

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude a group if all items in that group has CATEGORY field value equals to "work commenced". In other words, if any item in a group has value other than "work commenced", you want to include that group. That can be achieved using LINQ `Any()` like so :

```
List<Requirement> result = 
                    requirements.GroupBy(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
                                .Where(g => g.Any(item => item.Category != "work commenced")
                                .Select(cl => new Requirement
                                {
                                    ......
                                }).OrderByDescending(l => l.CRMOpportunityNumber)
                                .ToList();
```